# Combine predicates on two joined tables with OR

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables:

```sql
t_tbl
-----
t_id PK
t

p_tbl
-----
p_id PK
p

x_tbl
-----
x_id PK
x
t_id
p_id
```

My searches work separately:

Query 1:

```sql
SELECT x
FROM x_tbl xt
INNER JOIN
t_tbl tt
ON
xt.t_id = tt.t_id
```

Query 2:

```sql
SELECT x
FROM x_tbl xt
INNER JOIN
p_tbl pt
ON xt.p_id = pt.p_id
```

But I want to get `xt.x` if `xt.t_id = tt.t_id` ***`OR`*** `xt.p_id = pt.p_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try two left joins and then evaluate to see if one or the other was found:

```
select
  x.x
from
  x_tbl x
  left join p_tbl p on
    p.p_id = x.p_id
  left join t_tbl t on
    t.t_id = x.t_id
where
  p.i_id is not null or t.t_id is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe `UNION` the results together?

```
SELECT x FROM x_tbl xt INNER JOIN t_tbl tt ON xt.t_id = tt.t_id
UNION
SELECT x FROM x_tbl xt INNER JOIN p_tbl pt ON xt.p_id = pt.p_id
```

Comment: It is very unusual that this would return no results if each of your original queries did...

Comment: Ya sorry. I had commented out the function call in my code so nothing was returned.  There is a problem still though.  x is type xml in my table.  I get this error: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: could not identify an equality operator for type xml.     It works seperately though without the union.

Comment: Can you post the DDL for these tables?

Answer (score 0):

Any `JOIN` can *multiply* rows it it find multiple matches on the other side.  (It's not clear from the description if that can happen in your db design.) It doesn't seem like you'd want that. And it gets very expensive quickly with many rows on the other side and/or multiple joins.

Seems like you want ***1 row*** from `x_tbl`, where the conditions are met.
[**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) is the safe way that never multiplies rows in `x_tbl`.
It should also be fastest.

```sql
SELECT x.x
FROM   x_tbl x
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM t_tbl t WHERE t.t_id = x.t_id)
OR     EXISTS (SELECT FROM p_tbl p WHERE p.p_id = x.p_id)
```

This can happen with 2x `LEFT JOIN`:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)